"In follow" or "on follow"
Help me which answer righted between "in follow" and "on follow"?
There's come from a sentence: We took a taxi and Ben followed .... his motorbike.
Please give me some hint, thanks.
Have a nice day!

Hint: does the rider get into a motorbike?

Welcome to ELL, Vo Minh.  You are complicating matters by linking follow and in/on.  In this sentence, follow is a main verb. In/on is a preposition that links the mode of transport. If it was a car, you would use in,  and for a motorbike you would use on... simply because you sit in a car, and on a motorbike.  Note that, for public transport (bus, car, plane) you can use either in or on.

The choice between in and on has nothing to do with the verb (followed). It's entirely a matter of the relevant noun phrase (his motorbike).
Ben might follow someone on his bike or a skateboard, or he might follow in a car. The preposition mainly depends on whether the noun is seen as a container (that you'd be in) or a surface (that you'd be on).
But some things you just have to learn. It's always in a car, but you usually travel on a bus (and you can also travel by bus, for example).
